# How can I enable split screens on my windows pc so when I code in VS code I can see the changes in my code w/out having to refresh?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When I code in VS code I constantly have to flip in and out of my file and ide in order to see the changes I've made. How can I enable split screens so that when I code I see everything being changed in one whole screen? Without having to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, minimize vs code and browser.
Then fit both of them on the screen according to your desire.